# Using SELECT IIF result in another SELECT IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Here is my query, I'm using Access VBA to write the SQL query

```vb
Private Sub cmdRunQuery_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdRunQuery_Click
    Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strSQL, strA As String
    Dim strWhereA, strWhere As String
    Dim strIN, strDate As String
    Dim strPrice, strB As String
    Dim SelectAll As Boolean
    Dim varItem As Variant

    Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
                   
    strSQL = "SELECT IIF(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[StartDate]<=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.[EndDate]>=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date],(INT([Forms]![Filter]![End Date])-INT([Forms]![Filter]![Start Date])+1),IIF" & _
             "(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[StartDate]<=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.[EndDate]<=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date],(INT(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[EndDate])-INT([Forms]![Filter]![Start Date])+1),IIF" & _
             "(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[StartDate]>=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.[EndDate]<=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date],(INT(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[EndDate])-INT(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[StartDate])+1),IIF " & _
             "(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[StartDate]>=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.[EndDate]>=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date],(INT([Forms]![Filter]![End Date])-INT(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[StartDate])+1),0)))) " & _
             "AS Duration " & _
             "FROM (((DAILY_ACTIVITY INNER JOIN [DOR_TYPE] ON DAILY_ACTIVITY.[DOR] = [DOR_TYPE].[DOR]) INNER JOIN [WORK_TYPE] ON DAILY_ACTIVITY.WorkType = WORK_TYPE.[Work Type]) INNER JOIN [ADDITIONAL_TYPE] ON DAILY_ACTIVITY.AdditionelType = ADDITIONAL_TYPE.[Additionel Type])INNER JOIN ON [LOCATION] (DAILY_ACTIVITY.[FromLocation1]=LOCATION.[Location] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.[ToLocation5]=LOCATION.[Location])"
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhereA = " WHERE ((DAILY_ACTIVITY.StartDate<=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.EndDate>=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date]) " & _
                "OR (DAILY_ACTIVITY.StartDate<=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.EndDate<=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date] AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.EndDate)>=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date]) " & _
                "OR (DAILY_ACTIVITY.StartDate>=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.EndDate<=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date])" & _
                "OR (DAILY_ACTIVITY.StartDate>=[Forms]![Filter]![Start Date] AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.EndDate>=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date] AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.StartDate)<=[Forms]![Filter]![End Date]))" & _
                "AND (([DOR_TYPE].Category)<>'Rejected')"
    
    'Join SELECT and Main WHERE Clause
    strSQL = strSQL & strWhereA
        
    'WORKTYPE: Build the IN string by looping through the Work Type listbox
    For i = 0 To WorkType_List.ListCount - 1
        If WorkType_List.Selected(i) Then
            If WorkType_List.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & WorkType_List.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.WorkType in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
    
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False

    'SERVICE CLASS: Build the IN string by looping through the Service Classification listbox
    For i = 0 To ServiceClassification_List.ListCount - 1
        If ServiceClassification_List.Selected(i) Then
            If ServiceClassification_List.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & ServiceClassification_List.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.ServiceClassification in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
               
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False
    
    
    'VESSEL: Build the IN string by looping through the Vessel listbox
    For i = 0 To Vessel_List.ListCount - 1
        If Vessel_List.Selected(i) Then
            If Vessel_List.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & Vessel_List.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.Vessel in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
               
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False
    
    'FROM LOCATION: Build the IN string by looping through the FROM LOC listbox
    For i = 0 To FromLocation.ListCount - 1
        If FromLocation.Selected(i) Then
            If FromLocation.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & FromLocation.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.From_Location1 in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
               
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False
    
    'TO LOCATION: Build the IN string by looping through the TO LOC listbox
    For i = 0 To ToLocation.ListCount - 1
        If ToLocation.Selected(i) Then
            If ToLocation.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & ToLocation.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.To_Location5 in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
               
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False
    
    'REQUESTER: Build the IN string by looping through the REQUESTER listbox
    For i = 0 To REQUESTER.ListCount - 1
        If REQUESTER.Selected(i) Then
            If REQUESTER.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & REQUESTER.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.Requester in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
               
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False
    
    'SPV IN CHARGE: Build the IN string by looping through the SPV IN CHARGE listbox
    For i = 0 To SPVInCharge.ListCount - 1
        If SPVInCharge.Selected(i) Then
            If SPVInCharge.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & SPVInCharge.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (DAILY_ACTIVITY.SupervisionInCharge in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
               
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False
    
    'SITE: Build the IN string by looping through the SITE listbox
    For i = 0 To FromSite.ListCount - 1
        If FromSite.Selected(i) Then
            If FromSite.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & FromSite.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (LOCATION.Site in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
               
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False
    
    'CUSTODIAN: Build the IN string by looping through the CUSTODIAN listbox
    For i = 0 To FromCustodian.ListCount - 1
        If FromCustodian.Selected(i) Then
            If FromCustodian.Column(1, i) = "ALL" Then
                SelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & FromCustodian.Column(1, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = "AND (LOCATION.Custodian in " & _
                 "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & "))"
    strIN = ""
               
    'If "ALL" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not SelectAll Then
        strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
    SelectAll = False
    
    strA = "SELECT IIF(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[WorkType]='C.1. Personnel' OR DAILY_ACTIVITY.[WorkType]='C.2. Equipment',(Duration*ADDITIONAL_TYPE.[Daily Unit Price]), IIF" & _
           "(DAILY_ACTIVITY.[WorkType]<>'C.1. Personnel' AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.[WorkType]<>'C.2. Equipment' AND DAILY_ACTIVITY.[StartDate]>#31/7/2020#, (Duration*WORK_TYPE.[Unit Price_082020]), (Duration*WORK_TYPE.[Unit Price_062019])))" & _
           " AS Prices, Duration, * FROM ("
           
    strSQL = strA & strSQL & ") ORDER BY DAILY_ACTIVITY.[StartDate]"
      
    'MyDB.QueryDefs.Delete "Filter_Query"
    Set qdef = MyDB.CreateQueryDef("Filter_Query", strSQL)

    'Open the query and report, built using the IN clause to set the criteria
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Filter_Query", acViewNormal
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Daily Activity Report", acViewReport
    
    'Price Query
    strPrice = "SELECT WORK_TYPE.ID, DAILY_ACTIVITY.[WorkType], Sum(Duration) AS Total_Duration, Sum(Prices) AS Total_Price FROM ("
    strSQL = strPrice & strSQL & ") GROUP BY DAILY_ACTIVITY.[WorkType], WORK_TYPE.[ID], WORK_TYPE.[Unit Price_082020] ORDER BY WORK_TYPE.ID"
    
    MyDB.QueryDefs.Delete "Price_Query"
    Set qdef = MyDB.CreateQueryDef("Price_Query", strSQL)

    'Open the query and report, built using the IN clause to set the criteria
    'DoCmd.OpenQuery "Price_Query", acViewNormal
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Pricing Report", acViewReport
    
    'Clear listbox selection after running query
    'For Each varItem In Me.WorkType_List.ItemsSelected
    '    Me.WorkType_List.Selected(varItem) = False
    'Next varItem


Exit_cmdRunQuery_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdRunQuery_Click:

    If Err.Number = 5 Then
        MsgBox "You must make a selection(s) from the list" _
               , , "Selection Required !"
        Resume Exit_cmdRunQuery_Click
    Else
        'Write out the error and exit the sub
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Exit_cmdRunQuery_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

I need to get the result of price with those if condition. But then I got error message 'Syntax FROM Clause error'.

Other than that, I want to get the result of 2 aliases column: FromSite and ToSite based on FromLocation1 and ToLocation5 field in DAILY_ACTIVITY table which I had lookup table of Location and Site information in LOCATION table. These 2 aliases will become the additional WHERE Condition.

Comment: It is not necessary to prefix fields with table name unless query involves multiple tables that have same field names. What you posted does not look like VBA constructed SQL. Review http://www.baldyweb.com/BuildSQL.htm. Does this query work in query builder? Why are there spaces on each side of ! character?

Comment: Actually I only shows the SQL query part of my VBA. Here's the complete query.

Comment: Try assigning an alias table name to the inner query - that is the dataset the outer query would pull data from, not Daily_Activity or Work_Type. `AS DA ORDER BY Start Date;`.  Again, does query work in query builder?

Comment: Actually I only shows the SQL query part of my VBA. I had put the complete query VBA constructed SQL. The spaces beside ! was generated itself, actually I don't use the spaces on the query.

Comment: I am not seeing reason for error in the VBA constructed SQL. Still haven't answered my question - does query work in query builder?

Comment: No, the error message is "Syntax error in FROM Clause"

Comment: This piece is wrong: `INNER JOIN ON [LOCATION]`  What happens if you change that to  `INNER JOIN [LOCATION] ON`?

Comment: Ah, good eyes @HansUp!